# Error al subir data a DB en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Basicamente tengo lo siguiente en mi controller:

```
    $title_input = strip_tags($this->input->post('title'));
    $slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $title_input);
    $slug = strtolower($slug);

    if($title_input != ''){
        $data = array(
            'title' => $title_input,
            'slug'  => $slug,
        );
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'title' =>  'Untitled',
            'slug'  =>  'untitled',
        );
    }

    $data = array(
        'body'          => strip_tags($this->input->post('body')),
    );

    if($post_image != ''){
        $data['post_image'] = $post_image;
    }

    $this->Post_model->add($data);
```

Lo que estoy intentando es subir informacion mediante un Modal en donde tengo tres inputs cuyos son los siguientes:

- Title
- Body
- Post_image

Y el problema que estoy teniendo es que si el usuario opta por dejar vacio el input de title, este deberia subir como valor 'Untitled' y en su slug lo mismo 'untitled' pero si el input del valor de title no esta vacio, entonces deberia de subir la informacion especificada.

El comportamiento actual al dejar el input de title vacio, no me sube nada(no title, no body, no post_image) pero cuando escribo algo en dicho input(title) no me sube el body(pero la post_image y el title si)...para dejarlo mas claro:

input title vacio:

- No sube nada a DB

input title no vacio:

- title
- no body
- post_image

y lo que quiero al dejar el input title vacio pero no el body:

- untitled
- body
- post_image

**UPDATE:** Esta es lo que tengo en mi view

```
            <?php $args = array(
                'id'    => 'user_form',
            ) ?>
            <?= form_open_multipart('users/newmedia', $args); ?>
                <!-- Title -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= form_label('Title:', 'title'); ?>
                    <?php $data = array(
                        'id'    =>  'title',
                        'name'  =>  'title',
                        'class' =>  'form-control',
                        'value' =>  set_value('title'),
                    ); ?>
                    <?= form_input($data); ?>
                </div>
                <!-- Description -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= form_label('Description:', 'body'); ?>
                    <?php $data = array(
                        'id'    =>  'body',
                        'name'  =>  'body',
                        'class' =>  'form-control',
                        'value' =>  set_value('body'),
                        'style' =>  'max-width: 100%'
                    ); ?>
                    <?= form_textarea($data); ?>
                </div>
                <!-- File Input -->
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label class="input-group-btn">
                        <span class="btn btn-warning">
                            Browse 
                            <?php $data = array(
                                    'id'    =>  'post_image',
                                    'name'  =>  'post_image',
                                    'class' =>  'form-control',
                                    'value' =>  set_value('post_image'),
                                    'style' =>  'display:none',
                                ); ?>
                                <?= form_upload($data, '', ''); ?>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
                </div>
                <!-- Submit -->
                <hr>
                <?php $args = array(
                    'id'    =>  'mysubmit',
                    'class' =>  'btn btn-warning btn-sm'
                ); ?>
                <?= form_submit('mysubmit', 'Create', $args); ?>

            <?= form_close(); ?>
```

Nose si me explico pero espero me ayuden con este pequeno query que deseo crear, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo hagas un "echo" de los datos que te llegan y despues utiliza "die;" para que deje de ejecutarse y ver lo que te llega en pantalla. Parece que los datos no te llegan como deberían.

Comment: Ese es el problema xD, uso var_debug($data) juston despues de enviar la data al metodo de add en el post_model y no me muestra nada, literalmente.

Comment: Pues mira que al recibirlos con $this->input->post('title') te esten llegando y si el nombre 'title' esta en el formulario. Si en el formulario el input no tiene ese nombre no te va a mandar nada.

Comment: Pues asi mismo le tengo xD, nose porque, tengo varios metodos similares y hasta ahora este es el unico que me ha fallado.

Answer (score 0):

La posibilidad que se me ocurre es que puedes estar pisandote la variable `$data` y que por eso en algún momento borras los datos anteriores. Te recomiendo crear la variable `$data` de una sola vez.

```
$title_input = strip_tags($this->input->post('title'));
$body = strip_tags($this->input->post('body'));
$post_image = $this->input->post('post_image');
    $slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $title_input);
    $slug = strtolower($slug);

    if($title_input != ''){
        $data = array(
            'title' => $title_input,
            'slug'  => $slug,
            'body'  =>  $body,
            if($post_image != ''){
             'post_image'  =>  $post_image,
        );
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'title' =>  'Untitled',
            'slug'  =>  'untitled',
            'body'  =>  $body,
            if($post_image != ''){
             'post_image'  =>  $post_image,
            }
        );
    }

    $this->Post_model->add($data);
```